# iptables in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall

i want to stop iptables firewall in ubuntu.
how can i do that???

Answer (score 6):

All policies in iptables are ACCEPT by default in Ubuntu. Anyway to make sure
`sudo iptables -F` should take care of it.  it will flush all of the iptables rules.  iptables doesn't run like a service, it is a kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

All policies in iptables are ACCEPT by default in Ubuntu. This means you shouldn't notice the firewall at all (because it is doing nothing). You shouldn't have any problems with it that could need disabling iptables.

If something is not ACCEPT at your system or you have additional rules, maybe you have installed some script that is messing it up. In that way only you can know what that script is and how to disable it.